# Choosing the shell that SSH uses?

Tags: ssh, shell

How do I set the shell that is used when a user SSHs to a server. For example I can't stand BASH and need to use ZSH, how do I make it so ZSH is loaded along with my profile (`.zsh_profile`) when I ssh to the machine.

I dont want to have to pass a bunch of parameters with ssh either, can't I set the default shell?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you can't change your default shell, `ssh -t user@host 'zsh -l'` works.

The `-t` flag forces a pseudo-tty allocation, and the `-l` flag spawns a [login shell](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html).

Comment: For accessing a windows machine, you can use: `ssh -t <user@hostname> "powershell"`, or *pwsh*.)

Comment: If you'd like to automatically append that command via `~/.ssh/config` so you don't have to type it each time, [check this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1497747/87893)

Answer (score 57):

Assuming you're running on Linux, you can use the `chsh` command.

```
chsh -s /bin/ksh foo
chsh -s /bin/bash username
```

Comment: Please note that the path to the binary has to be in `/etc/shells` for the shell to be selectable.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have this command.

Comment: @david.perez Yes it does, in [the `passwd` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/passwd).

Comment: This doesn't work when authentication is handled via LDAP

Comment: How is this SSH-specific??

Comment: `chsh` changes the login shell. That might have unintended consequences. Let alone it doesn't address the question as such.

Answer (score 14):

`man chsh` changes shell, does not always work

Alternatively, you can stick `exec /bin/zsh` in your bash login script.this will replace bash instance with your shell.

Or you can do `ssh host "zsh -l"`

Comment: Why the -1 (15 chars...)?

Comment: that is a lower case `L`

Comment: `ssh -t` is required to get a TTY for last options. By default if a command (like `zsh -l`) is provided, OpenSSH would do a non-login shell, which would not allocate TTY for you, and `-l` won't change that (because that is executed after log in).

Answer (score 13):

Edit /etc/passwd (if you have the rights, or ask your system admin) to change your default shell.

Comment: For some reason the users I recently created had no default shell. This worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks this answer is great. I didn't have a shell here either. I found the line myusername:x:1000:1000::/home/myusername: and added /bin/bash to the end. Log out and in and my ssh session is using bash :)

Comment: Can you explain how to edit this file?--meaning what changes to make to change the default shell?

Comment: I think the answer in https://serverfault.com/a/106723/3835 is much better to avoid messing directly with the file

Comment: It's far safer and easier to use proper tools for this purpose, e.g. `usermod --shell /bin/zsh someuser`

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure how you can put your local `.zshrc` to remote server, (that's without permanently storing it there), this works for me to change my login shell on remote server.

Since it's a shared account, I can use `zsh` only for myself with this method.

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config` file in your local machine.

```
Host yourServer
    HostName <IP, FQDN or DNS resolvable name>
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your keyfile>
    RemoteCommand zsh -l
    RequestTTY force
    User <yourUsername>
```

There could be hackish way to accomplish what you are looking for, like below.

*WARNING* **This comes with no guarantees and doesn't look 'wise', however I did managed to put my local file to server and source it in login shell using this.**

```
Host someHost
    HostName someIP
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/somekey.pem
    RemoteCommand zsh -l -c 'sleep 1; source /tmp/somefile; zsh'
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand bash -c 'sftp %r@%h <<< "put /tmp/somefile /tmp/somefile"'
    RequestTTY force
    User someUser
```

How it works?

- `RemoteCommand` defines what needs to be run on remote side.
- `LocalCommand` defines what needs to be run on local, which is used to copy your local file to remote server for sourcing it. Here is the catch, it happens only after 'successful' connection to remote host.

Meaning:

1. Your connection to remote should be open and alive
2. Your remote shell doesn't have the file yet, so it has to wait till file is there, ergo `sleep`
3. Your local uses `sftp` to put your file to remote server, remote server wakes up from `sleep` and sources your scripts.

It's super hackish, I'd like to know if there is a better way, too.

Update:
This can be used instead of 'long' sleep time:
`RemoteCommand zsh -l -c 'while [[ ! -f /tmp/somefile ]]; do sleep 0.05; done; source /tmp/somefile; zsh'`

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Windows:

- to use PowerShell 5, use `ssh -t <username@servername> "powershell"`
- to use PowerShell Core, use `ssh -t <username@servername> "pwsh"`
- to use `bash` (Git Bash or WSL), use `ssh -t <username@servername> "bash"`

Comment: this was already been told in the comments

Answer (score 1):

About the original question: change the shell opened by a SSH session, I don't think that it is configurable.
You can change the shell used by the user on the system (`chsh`, or edit /etc/passwd), or even change the default shell of the machine, but not the SSH shell (I think SSH just opens a regular session with the user's parameters, including shell configuration).